# Is Homeland S08 set in 2018 or 2020?

Tags: homeland

Is (the bulk of) S08 supposed to have been set in 2018 or 2020?

There seems to have been a mistake about this:

In S08E06, CNB (TV news channel) lists birth and death years of the deceased President as "1941–2020":

[image]

I was a bit confused about this. At the time I found this quote by producer Alex Gansa to Entertainment Weekly in [2018](https://ew.com/tv/2018/04/19/homeland-final-season) that I thought might explain it:

> We're going to start fresh in season 8 and probably do a fairly big time jump between 7 and 8 and put any Trump parallels behind us

So I thought that maybe somehow S08 had jumped forward to 2020 (even though that would be inconsistent with S07).

However, in tonight's season and series finale (S08E12), the blurb of Carrie's book says:

> In 2018, former CIA Case Officer and Station Chief Carrie A. Mathison made what ......
>
> was in her mind the most patriotic move she could make: she outed an American spy to the Russian government. In exchange, the Russian government released audio from [...]

[image]

One of the above seems to be a mistake. So which is it? Is (the bulk of) S08 supposed to have been set in 2018 or 2020?

Comment: Why can't we (the audience) see something in a scene (purportedly taking place in the year 2020) that shows something, e.g., a book published in 2018 - i.e., dating back to 2018, or referencing something that happened in 2018?

Comment: but the 2nd scene in question happened 2 years after the 1st scene...also the 2nd scene's description of certain events were for events that happened around the time of the 1st scene...right? @Alex

Comment: @Alex: Please. If you haven't watched the entire series/season, don't add comments.